Savings when money market is in equilibrium (LM curve in IS-LM model)
When the money market is in equilibrium, supply of real money balances is equal to the money people hold in hand as liquidity, right? Which means entire real money balance is at hand as liquidity (which means no savings???)! Then how come there are savings which will provide funds for investments in goods markets which can be borrowed at equilibrium interest rate r? What am I missing?
